# How to configure Visual Studio to show integers as decimals when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, integer, decimal

My Visual Studio 2008 debugger is showing integers as hexadecimals, how to correct that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click in the debug window and disable Hexadecimal Display.

Comment: I was able to rightClick on the QuickWatch window to disable the hex display.  Thanks.. this was driving me nuts!

Comment: Just to point this out where to find exactly this checkbox.
1. Hover over a variable to open the quick watch popup WHILE (!) debugging.
2. Right click INTO (!) the popup.
3. Check if you find at the end of the list "[X] Hexadecimal Display".
=> There you go.

Answer (score 3):

Right click any of the debugging windows and 'De-select' the Hexadecimal Display option. -

Answer (score 2):

While debugging right click any variable and in the tooltip you can toggle Hex display on/off. There's also a Hex button on the debug toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just specific values to appear as hex, add a ,x to the end of the debug expression, as in:

Value,x

Comment: what if I want the other way around ? i.e.: specific value to appear in decimal ?